# Converting number to asterisk (Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

How would I go about converting an integer to a character such as asterisk?
For instance:

```
+-----+---------+
| Int |   Ast   |
+-----+---------+
|   1 | *       |
|   5 | *****   |
|   3 | ***     |
|   7 | ******* |
|   2 | **      |
+-----+---------+


Format([Int],"**") AS Expr1
```

I've been using the format function as seen above, but this doesn't appear to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access has the `string()` function (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/String-Function-4808c43b-7640-4334-87fc-457499c185b1)).  So you can do:

```
select repeat([Int], '*')
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think it'd be that easy. Thanks for the help!